# Pinyin "ying" has an "o" sound?

Tags: pronunciation, pinyin

Look at 1:54 and 5:22 of this video: [Chinese Pinyin in 6 Mins](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=b9Ayvjy-Dgs)

Is `ying` really pronounced with an "o" sound?  This seems counterintuitive, especially when `yin` (at 1:49 in the video) sounds as a native English speaker would expect.

Comment: I think the pronunciation largely depends on which part of China the speaker comes from. In that video, I sense a distinctive northern China accent.

Comment: This pronunciation can be found in very standardised Taiwanese Mandarin as well, such as heard on language proficiency exams and similar.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In IPA transcriptions of Chinese, `ying` is usually written as: [iŋ]. This is exactly like `yin`, except with an "ng" sound. However, as you noticed, some people pronounce it a little differently. [This paper](http://online.sfsu.edu/~wenchao/presentations/phonetic.pdf) (page 9) transcribes the alternate pronunciation as [iɘŋ]. Wouldn't really call it an "o" sound, but the vowel *is* different than that of the `yin`.